# Why does the following code giving different outputs for different execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
class Program
{
    public static void ThreadMainMethod()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread Proc{0}",i);
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMainMethod));
        t.Start();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From Main Thread");
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
        t.Join();
    }
```

Comment: Because concurrency is inherently non-deterministic unless synchronized.

Comment: "Knock! Knock! Race condition. Who's there?"

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not define an order that is should be run in.  You have four counting threads, each thread runs completely independently of each other.   Windows will run the threads in what ever order it's scheduler determines - which is affected by every other process in your system.

If you do not synchronize your threads there is no guarantee in which order they will run.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to synchronize this program @shf301

Comment: That would depend on how you want to synchronize the program.  You need to first define the order.   But multi-threaded synchronization is a large and complicated area.  Here's just the list of the different types you can use in .Net: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xyf641a(v=vs.110).aspx